# What is the shape on the Wakandan case?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

In episode 5 of *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*, Bucky gives Sam a case which he says originated in Wakanda. It’s not revealed what is inside the case during this episode, but there are a few very clear shots of the outside. This is what's on it's cover:

Full view with the hinge at the bottom:
[image]

Blurry view showing the side:
[image]

I don't happen to recognize this shape, symbol, or pattern from the MCU or the comics. But it certainly seems to be deliberate.

It might be a sort of face (perhaps upside down), but that could just be because it is symmetric. Its not the same as [the Wakandan flag](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wakanda?file=Flag_of_Wakanda.png) which does have a panther as a main element, however, but it could be intended to be evocative of that.

What is it?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned it might be a modern redesign of [Soundwave](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jsfNGzWf1gM/Us7mL10nOBI/AAAAAAAANZA/ta0Ri_zfAyQ/s1600/soundwave.jpg).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the shape is supposed to be evocative of wings. Sam is the Falcon and he wore the EXO-7 Falcon suit. However, earlier in the episode Walker had ripped the wings off of the suit breaking it. Sam then leaves the suit with Torres. So he now has no wings. Later in the episode Bucky calls in a favour with the Wakandans and goes to Sam with the crate.

> **Bucky:** Just dropping this off. You can sign for it and I'll go. I called in a favor from the Wakandans.
>
> <sub>*The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*, Season 1 Episode 5, “Truth”</sub>

Now the whole episode has essentially been dedicated to character development on all fronts but primarily focused on Sam. Sam’s development has been on whether or not he will take on the mantle as the new Captain America. He eventually decides to. Now given Sam already has the shield, the box is unlikely to contain a new one. So, the likelihood is that it is a new suit, probably with integrated wings. Given the design on the front is reminiscent of stylised wings: two wing-like shapes extend from a central structure.

Given that the case did in fact contain a new Captain America suit with wings this is almost certainly what it was meant to be. We’ll likely know for sure in the Art Of book as well when that releases.

[image: Sam in the new suit with the wings spread]

---

Just to be as complete as possible, whilst it could just be generic Wakandan shapes, we do see the box that Bucky is given with his new arm in it from *Avengers: Infinity War*. This does not have the same design.

[image: Close on the box containing Bucky’s new arm]

It also doesn’t seem to match the design on Steve’s Wakandan shields, also seen in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

[image: Steve inspects the new shield on his arm whilst standing next to T’Challa]

Comment: I thought the same thing when looking at OP's first picture. If viewed from the angle of a person opening the box (hinge at the top). the center bar would be a person and it would clearly look like wings spread out and tapering down towards the ground.

Comment: I assumed it contained a new Falcon suit. Though looking at the still shot, it is also somewhat reminiscent of the Transformer logo.

Comment: Falcon's wings designed and provided by Black Panther (I guess you could sub in Wakanda in this instance) is also a comic reference in itself: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Falcon%27s_Wings
The actual symbol might easily be part of that reference given the week-by-week release structure of the show, and the cliff-hangery nature of the contents' reveal.