# Are these the original wings?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

**spoilers for the TFATWS finale**

In the finale for TFATWS, we see Sam in his full Captain America ensemble, complete with his wings.  The whole outfit is obviously changed, but are these wings his original ones?  I thought, after John damaged Sam's original wings and Sam left them with Torres, that Sam might become Captain America without his wings, breaking away from being Falcon.  However, Bucky gets a "favor" from the Wakandans and leaves a case with Sam, of which we never see the contents.

Did the Wakandans make Sam a brand new set of wings, or did they fix up the old ones?  I thought that Torres would be fixing up and using the older wings in the finale if that were the case, but since we never see him with the older wings it brings up the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They’re new wings, compare with the two below. Note the different shapes of the structural section at the top from the back as well as the slightly different shape overall.

[image: Sam in his wings hovering from ep1]

[image: Sam in his new wings from ep2]

Aside from that it makes sense these are different than the other ones. He left the old EXO-7 Falcon wings with Torres and never goes back to them again. In fact the two barely speak on screen after that point and not in person. Then we have Bucky call in a favour from the Wakandans and bring a Wakandan case to Sam. Sam opens this case at the end of Ep5 and the next we see of him in Ep6 he’s in the new suit with the wings. It’s clearly meant to be the suit and wings from the case.

Also it would be odd for Bucky to ask the Wakandans to make Sam a suit but not with wings in my opinion. Else he could really ask anyone else he knows. The speciality of the Wakandans is advanced technology so using them to make the wings seems most likely.

I would also like to note that as we see in [this related answer of mine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/246055/58193), the shape on the case is of stylised wings.

[image: The case that Bucky gives Sam]

Comment: nice catch on the wing like shape on the case